# couldn't install quanteda either directly or via source

Tags: r, text, nlp, quanteda

I've tried directly install the package, its github version or from the source to no avail.

This is the error message:

```
During startup - Warning messages:
1: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C" 
2: Setting LC_TIME failed, using "C" 
3: Setting LC_MESSAGES failed, using "C" 
4: Setting LC_MONETARY failed, using "C" 
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-    L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15/6.1.0'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib'
ld: library not found for -lgfortran
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see     invocation)
make: *** [quanteda.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'quanteda'
* removing     '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/quanteda'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package 'Downloads/quanteda_1.0.0.tar.gz' had non-zero     exit status
```

Direct install.package gives this error:

```
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/el-    capitan/contrib/3.4/quanteda_1.0.0.tgz': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/el-    capitan/contrib/3.4/quanteda_1.0.0.tgz'
Warning in install.packages :
  download of package 'quanteda' failed
tar: Failed to set default locale
```

this is my sessionInfo

```
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.2
```

thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you haven’t installed Xcode. See the macOS installation instructions at https://github.com/quanteda/quanteda.

Comment: thanks so much for the reply. with xcode still the same error message though

Comment: You have to launch Xcode at least once and install the command line tools.

Comment: somehow still error

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was an installation problem that was temporary and due to an attempt to install the package while CRAN's servers were still updating (a 2-3 day interim period). Problem is now gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem too. I solved it using `install.packages("quanteda")` and changing the CRAN server. Actually I used the Australia Melbourne 1

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work: install.packages('quanteda', repos='https://cran.ms.unimelb.edu.au/')

Comment: The issue was raised in between CRAN accepting the package and the binaries being built. Binaries are now available for v1.0.0 on all platforms so this should not be an issue any more.